# Reset Rank when Occurrences Repeat

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the rank of a particular event, group by user, and based on the date on which it occurs, but for the rank to reset each time the event repeats.

To illustrate, I want to get the rank in the `rank_i_want` column (but I can only manage to get the rank in the `rank_i_get` column, where the rank 'continues' when the event repeats). In the `rank_i_want` column, the rank goes back to 1 when the event occurs again for that user:

```
    date        food    name    rank_i_get  rank_i_want
0   2018-06-01  pizza   Mary    1           1
1   2018-06-02  pizza   Mary    2           2
2   2018-06-03  burger  Mary    1           1
3   2018-06-04  burger  Mary    2           2
4   2018-06-05  pizza   Mary    3           1
5   2018-06-06  burger  Mary    3           1
6   2018-06-03  pizza   Bob     1           1
7   2018-06-04  burger  Bob     1           1
8   2018-06-05  burger  Bob     2           2
9   2018-06-05  pizza   Bob     2           1
```

This is what I've tried so far (which yields the `rank_i_get` in the table above):

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': ['Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Bob' ,'Bob' ,'Bob', 'Bob'],
        'date': ['2018-06-01', '2018-06-02', '2018-06-03', '2018-06-04', '2018-06-05', '2018-06-06', '2018-06-03', '2018-06-04', '2018-06-05', '2018-06-05'], 
        'food': ['pizza', 'pizza', 'burger', 'burger', 'pizza', 'burger', 'pizza', 'burger', 'burger', 'pizza']})

a['rank_i_get'] = a.groupby(['name', 'food'])['date'].rank()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new `Series` by compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)d merged columns with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) and add [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for consecutive groups `Series`:

```
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])

s = a['name'] + '_' + a['food']
a['r'] = a.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())['date'].rank().astype(int)
```

Or:

```
a['r'] = a.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())['date'].cumcount().add(1)
```

---

```
print (a)
   name       date    food  r
0  Mary 2018-06-01   pizza  1
1  Mary 2018-06-02   pizza  2
2  Mary 2018-06-03  burger  1
3  Mary 2018-06-04  burger  2
4  Mary 2018-06-05   pizza  1
5  Mary 2018-06-06  burger  1
6   Bob 2018-06-03   pizza  1
7   Bob 2018-06-04  burger  1
8   Bob 2018-06-05  burger  2
9   Bob 2018-06-05   pizza  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
7    6
8    6
9    7
dtype: int32
```